# Reset values in useState([]) Reactjs/recharts

Tags: reactjs, use-state, recharts

I am using recharts within a react component. I am attempting to reset data within:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

currently I set the data as such:

```
const getData = (accData) => {
setData((currentData) => [...currentData, accData]);};
```

The data is sent to getData on a buttonClick. The idea is on every button click reset data and display just the new data. Yet the chart is displaying old data and the new therefore not resetting data. I cant seem to figure out how to reset data completely.

As you can see here the values are not resetting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZmkv.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW0T9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoWpF.png

Button Click

```
     <Button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "red", fontSize: 15, color: "#FFFFFF" }}
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => {
            onTestClick("startTest");
          }}
        >
          Start Test
          {<PlayCircleFilledWhiteIcon style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />}
        </Button>
```

onTestClick function

```
const onTestClick = (command) => {
console.log("On Test Command: ", command);
socket.emit("Test_Commands", command);
socket.on("limits", (limitData) => {
  setLimits(limitData);
});

socket.on("test_data", (data) => getData(data));
```

};

Aidan:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o65HN.png

First Start Test button click:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uIz.png

Second Start Test button click:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PngH4.png

LineChart:

```
<Grid item>
      <LineChart width={1000} height={240} data={data}>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stopColor="red" />

            <stop offset="100%" stopColor="black" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="value"
          stroke="#e82420"
          strokeDasharray="5 5"
        />
        <ReferenceLine y={lowerLimit} stroke="orange" alwaysShow={true} />
        <ReferenceLine y={threshold} stroke="green" alwaysShow={true} />
        <ReferenceLine y={upperLimit} stroke="orange" alwaysShow={true} />
        <XAxis dataKey="Time" />
        <YAxis dataKey="Value" />
      </LineChart>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
```

Comment: Can you show us your buttonClick function?

Comment: In the example you added to the question you're not using the getData function

Comment: I put it in the edit

Comment: @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga That was a mistake on my part as I was debugging while responding on here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need `currentData` then.
Just use the new `accData` when you set your data

```
setData([accData]);
```

Comment: Essentially with this: setData((currentData) => [...currentData, accData]);}; currentData comes in incrementally and displays it live from the backend. When I tried setting just setData([accData]); All I got was a single point of the values and not the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset data on button click, just do so in the `onClick` like so:

```js
onClick={() => {
    setData([]);
    onTestClick("startTest");
}}
```

Comment: In doing so it resets the graph which is a step in the right direction, but still displays duplicates. Ill attach an edit for you.

Comment: What is considered a "duplicate" in the screenshot?

Comment: Yeah if you look at the image I attached you can see that x repeats itself 1,1,1 2,2,2 etc and they have the same y value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with recharts. How are the x values defined? Are those coded by you, or is it some magic from recharts?

Comment: I believe the problem is actually in the recent edit I made showing the linechart. I believe where data={data} is storing the old data somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually had nothing to do with setData() or recharts. The issue was my own fault. I was essentially incrementing socket connections with every click of Start Test. That way first click socket(0) = {data} then second click socket(0) = {data} and socket(1) = {data}. Was not a duplication issue of values but a duplication issue of socket. Thank you to everyone who took a stab at it.